# iFrame containing video only appears on resize of the window

Tags: html, css

URL: http://discountvideoproduction.com/home2

When the window is scaled up, the iframe containing a video is not there. When scaled down to "iPhone" size, it appears. For the life of me I can't understand why it disappears at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Disable `automatic-responsive-tables` plugin. And if you installed it to help you with the layout of the page, delete it. `<table>`s and `display:table` are only meant for displaying tabular data. Use `display: block` or `display: flex` for your responsive layout, depending on the use-case. Read [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design) if you want to learn the basics of responsiveness.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. If you check now, I have two divs that are next to each other. Now how would I: 1) have it so that they don't cross over each other, 2) have the video size be responsive so that it shrinks in size with the browser, and 3) have the text move to underneath the video once the browser is shrinked enough.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Your request fits the classical pattern of `I don't have the time or the desire to learn how to do this, please do it for me`. If you are trying to learn, show us what you don't understand and we'll explain. If you're trying to get a job done, hire a professional.

Answer (score 0):

One of its parents is hidden inside /wp-content/plugins/automatic-responsive-tables/css/style.css?ver=4.5.3

```
@media (min-width: 1001px)
.art-table {
    display: none;
}
```